# Android Web request content format

Tags: android, request, web

I want to format the content I get from a specific website to show it on my device . For example , from this [page](http://golfnews.no/golfpaatv.php) I need only the program titles and the description of each one . I get the html code for this page with this function :

```
 private String getPage() {
        String str = "***";

        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://golfnews.no/golfpaatv.php");
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        return str;
    }
```

It returns a string which contains the html code. Now I want to have some strings containing the titles and other strings containing the description . I tried a few methods but I can't figure out what to do ! I am a beginner and I don't know much in android . Could you please help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of that URL, you just fetch RSS by using [this link](http://www.golfnews.no/feed.php?feed=1), and now parse the RSS either by using SAX Parser, DOM Parser or Pull Parser.

Comment: Could you please be more precise ? I am a beginner and I don't fully understand what you just said . If you could help me with a function , it would be perfect.

Comment: @George as you are passing the .php url above in HttpPost function, then just pass the above link which i have mentioned above. Now as you are getting RSS feed in XML format, you have parse this XML data by using SAX parser after that you will be having title and description data.